# Receiving a Notification when an already linkedin member (via api) changes main-address or email address

Tags: api, linkedin-api, profile

We can do the following with Facebook but cannot find details about how to do with linkedin despite hours of googling. I suspect its terminology.

I'm a designer for this, not a coder, and trying to assist the final dev team with as much detail as possible in my spec.

Can we receive a **callback / notification ** if a user changes their linkedin profile details (e.g. main-address) if they have previously oauthed with our site.

Following on, if the user deletes their linkedin account do we receive an update on this? e.g. user xxx has deregistered from linkedin, so we can choose to take some action (if we so choose)

I've easily found heaps of references to getting [profile info](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1206) (and the [fields](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1061)) e.g. linkedin docs, & a ruby API wrapper, but nothing comes up with information about notifications of changes. FYI we've found out how to do this in Facebook straight from the API docs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the LinkedIn API does not support 'real-time' notifications of profile changes, de-authorization, etc like the Facebook Graph API.  From the horses mouth:

http://developer.linkedin.com/message/4956#4956

Comment: Thanks Paul. Seeing the response and considering t&cs I can now see why. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as the answer.